# Debugging Error on counting empty squares

Tags: javascript

Given an array of arrays, count how many are empty. Notes: empty counts as: length of 0 (no elements), empty strings, and the number 0.

```
var squares1 = [[5], [0], [9], ['','', 10]]; 
 console.log(emptySquares(squares1)) //=> 1

var squares2 = [[],[0, ''],[]]; 
 console.log(emptySquares(squares2)) // => 3;

var squares3 = [['hello', 2], ['maybe'], ['10'], [100]];
 console.log(emptySquares(squares3)); //=> 0

function emptySquares(squares) {
  var total = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
      var isEmpty = true;
    for (var j = 0; j < squares[i].length; j++) {
      if (squares[i][j] !== '' || squares[i][j] !== 0 || squares[i].length === 0) {
        isEmpty = false;
    } 
    }
    if (isEmpty) {
      total += 1;
    }
  }
  return total;
}
```

Comment: So what is your question here?

Comment: my code isnt outputting the correct count and idk why

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure about the question, but I would go with a simple recursive design:

```js
const emptySquares = (()=>{
  let total = 0, a;
  return squares=>{
    for(let v of squares){
      a = v instanceof Array;
      if(a && v.length){
        total = emptySquares(v);
      }
      else if(a || v === '' || v === 0){
        total++;
      }
    }
    const r = total;
    total = 0;
    return r;
  }
})();

const squares1 = [[5], [0], [9], ['','', 10]]; 
console.log(emptySquares(squares1));

const squares2 = [[],[0, ''],[]];
console.log(emptySquares(squares2));

const squares3 = [['hello', 2], ['maybe'], ['10'], [100]];
console.log(emptySquares(squares3));
```